# How to get the same, just shuffled content in a div, from another one

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

register.php

```
$allCaps=array("img01.png", "img02.png", "img03.png"....);  // 20 images
shuffle($allCaps);  // this is critical point
$fiveCaps = array_slice($allCaps, 0, 5);

<td id="box01">
<?php
shuffle($fiveCaps);
echo "<img src=\"captcha/imgs/".$fiveCaps[0]."\">";
echo "<img src=\"captcha/imgs/".$fiveCaps[1]."\">";
... //all five images from $fiveCaps are placed here
?>  
</td>

<td id="box02">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#box02").load("register.php #box01")
</script> </td>
```

In box02  I want (and expected) the same images as in box01 (just shuffled).
But some another images appear in  box02 which don't exist in box01
If I remove "critical_point_line" - the images are the same in both boxes, but of course, allways only the first five images from $allCaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with just using a php function?

```
<?php
$allCaps=array("img01.png", "img02.png", "img03.png"....);  // 20 images
shuffle($allCaps);  // this is critical point
$fiveCaps = array_slice($allCaps, 0, 5);

function printRandom($caps)
{
  shuffle($caps);
  foreach($caps as $cap)
  {
    echo "<img src=\"captcha/imgs/".$cap."\">";
  }
}
?>     

<td id="box01">
<?php
   printRandom($fiveCaps);
?>  
</td>

<td id="box02">
<?php
   printRandom($fiveCaps);
?>  
</td>
```

The problem in your code points out thay you might not entirely understand jQuery's selector ;
Executing the following code :

```
$("#box02").load("register.php #box01")
```

will not load a new instance of `register.php`, and simply copy the contents of `#box1` (that we just filled up from our PHP code to `#box02`

If you want to shuffle the variable and print it in Javascript, you will need to find a way to pass it from PHP to Javascript.
A good way to do this, is with [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: @ Timothy, your solution works. Could you maybe find what is wrong in my code ? It should work, also.

Comment: I added a little more info on why your code did not work, and how you could make it work using both PHP and Javascript. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

why are you using jquery to shuffle it , why not straight something like this

```
    <td id="box-1">
        <?php $lista = shuffle($fivecaps);
            foreach($lista as &$imgcode){
                echo '<img src=\"captcha/imgs/"'.$imgcode.'"\">';
            }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td id="box-2">
        <?php $listb = shuffle($fivecaps);
            foreach($listb as &$imgcode){
                echo '<img src=\"captcha/imgs/"'.$imgcode.'"\">';
            }
        ?>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <td id="box02">
    <!-- just leave this empty -->
   </td>
```

And place this in your onload:

```
$("#box02").html($('#box1').html()); // <-- wouldn't this make it a lot easier?
```

If you want div `box1` in `box2`, why don't you just copy the html from `box1`? That makes it faster (one less servercall) and it's a lot easier to read.

Comment: not sure in that case if his shuffle function would work for box2, as he'll be copying the exact html content from box 1

Comment: @ rsplak, this is because I need a new shuffle in box02. So, the same images, but shuffled. If i just copy box01 - images are not shuffled